# Mobile rijndael algorithm implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, codenameone, rijndael

I have a mobile application generated by **codename one**, so it is going to work on all mobiles.
Its a Client-Server application. I have to store credit card info and some other private info.
I think for Encryption **Rijndael** would be the best.
i have used **MD5** before but now a days i think it is old

I don't know how to do that any help..??
How can i Encrypt the information on mobile app it self and then send that to server ..??
Or is there any other Encryption method better than **Rijndael** ..??

Answer (score 1):

`MD5` is not an encryption method, it's a hash function. Rijndael (a.k.a. `AES`) is supported out of the box in Java, although there might be some restrictions on the key size.

As a side note, I'm a bit worried that you would be handling credit card information, with a lacking knowledge about security.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and i know uses of **MD5**. I got things mixed up sorry for that. And I am really working hard to understand the encryption and security besides this is just a test application and it would be reviewed by my mentor. I just want to do it perfect.

Comment: Well, see the javax.crypto package for a start.

Comment: Encryption and attacking it is an ongoing battle. The non-solutions of today may have been valid in their time (quite a lot never were). Even tomorrow's perfect solution will have a limited window of validity. That said, I'd expect state-of-the-art encryption to be the least vulnerable part of a credit card system.

Comment: Well, the issue here is two-fold. You can already use SSL to transmit the data to a server in a secure fashion, without having to encrypt anything yourself. However if you're storing the data somewhere, it should be at least encrypted separately. Preferably it shouldn't be stored in a place (such as your phone) where an attacker can gain access to it.

Comment: Rijndael isn't AES, it's a superset. Some people get bitten by that, using Rijndael features not supported by AES and having interoperability issues.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of algorithms that are sometime better than **Rijndael** and sometimes worst, it is up to your need to decide [what encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms#Cryptography)  you need.

By the way as you asked about how to encrypt you can see this [link](http://www.efgh.com/software/rijndael.htm) about how to implement algorithm, and you can it implement it in almost every languages like this :

[Java](https://www.google.com/search?espv=2&q=rijndael%20java%20implementation&oq=rijndael%20java&gs_l=serp.3.1.0i67l2j0i20j0i67j0i22i30l6.170145.171178.0.173145.5.5.0.0.0.0.599.969.3-1j0j1.2.0....0...1c.1.58.serp..3.2.968.FNscyehM3N0)

[Objective C](https://www.google.com/search?espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&q=rijndael+implementation+objective+c&oq=rijndael+implementation+objective+c&gs_l=serp.3...576.3811.0.4051.12.10.0.0.0.0.553.1390.3-1j1j1.3.0....0...1c.1.58.serp..11.1.553.a-2eDUfq9jw)

[C++](https://www.google.com/search?espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&q=rijndael%20implementation%20C%2B%2B&oq=rijndael%20implementation%20C%2B%2B&gs_l=serp.3...25743.26533.0.27116.3.3.0.0.0.0.390.390.3-1.1.0....0...1c.1.58.serp..2.1.389.CX37IMoz17w)

And almost any language that you want.

Answer (score 0):

To user cryptographic algorithms in Codename One (hashing, encryption etc.) you can use the bouncy castle cn1lib: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/bouncy-castle-crypto-api

See the full list of 3rd party libraries for Codename One [here](http://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html).